# performing frequency table by group with calculation count of value in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lapply

Suppose this is my dataset

```
(dput)
dataset<-structure(list(group1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("b", "x"), class = "factor"), group2 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("g", "y"), class = "factor"), 
    var1 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("group1", 
"group2", "var1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
))
```

I need calculate frequency for two groups

```
x+y
b+g
```

and for variable var1, calculate count of 1 value and 2 value. For each group.
So the desired output

```
        total_count_of_group    var1-1  var1-2
x   y          5                   
                              3         2
b   g          4              2         2
```

This output mean that total_count_of_group x+y=5 obs. by this group.
where 1 value meets 3 times and 2 value two times.

similary
total_count_of_group b+g=4 obs. by this group.
where 1 value meets 2 times and 2 value two times.

How to get such table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved in two steps:

1. Aggregate group totals and update `dataset`
2. Reshape from long to wide format

using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dataset)[, total_count_of_group := .N, by =. (group1, group2)], 
      group1 + group2 + total_count_of_group~ paste0("var1=", var1), length)
```

> ```
>    group1 group2 total_count_of_group var1_1 var1_2
> 1:      b      g                    4      2      2
> 2:      x      y                    5      3      2
> ```

Please, note that this will work for an arbitrary number of different values in `var1` as well as an arbitrary number of groups.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyverse)

dataset %>%
  group_by(group1, group2) %>%             # for each combination of groups
  mutate(counts = n()) %>%                 # count number of rows
  count(group1, group2, var1, counts) %>%  # count unique combinations 
  spread(var1, n, sep = "_") %>%           # reshape dataset
  ungroup()                                # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#   group1 group2 counts var1_1 var1_2
#   <fct>  <fct>   <int>  <int>  <int>
# 1 b      g           4      2      2
# 2 x      y           5      3      2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could produce three tables, select the relevant counts, and then combine in a dataframe.

```
a <- table(dataset$group1, dataset$group2)
b <- table(dataset$var1[dataset$group1=='x'])
d <- table(dataset$var1[dataset$group1=='b'])

data.frame(total_count_of_group = c(a[2,2], a[1,1]), 
           var1_1 = c(b[1], b[2]),
           var1_2 = c(d[1], d[2]))

  total_count_of_group var1_1 var1_2
1                    5      3      2
2                    4      2      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `base R`

```
out <- aggregate(cbind(var = rep(1, nrow(df1))) ~ ., 
    transform(df1, counts = ave(var1, group1, group2, FUN = length)), length)
reshape(out, idvar = c('group1', 'group2', 'counts'),
     timevar= 'var1', direction= 'wide')
#   group1 group2 counts var.1 var.2
#1      b      g      4     2     2
#3      x      y      5     3     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution :

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset %>%
  group_by(group1, group2) %>%
  summarize(total = n(), x = list(table(var1) %>% as_tibble %>% spread(var1,n))) %>%
  unnest

# # A tibble: 2 x 5
# # Groups:   group1 [2]
#   group1 group2 total   `1`   `2`
#   <fct>  <fct>  <int> <int> <int>
# 1 b      g          4     2     2
# 2 x      y          5     3     2
```